# How to fire WebBrowser RaiseEvent in console application c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, webbrowser-control, raiseevent

So basically I'm trying to fire WebBrowser's RaiseEvent from console applicaton but it does not work. In WinForms project it works well, so I'm just wondering what I have to do to make it work in console app. Is this even possible?

This is how I create thread for my WB

```
 private static Thread runBrowserThread(int mCandidatePosition)
        {
            var wbThread =  new Thread(() => {              
                mClient = new WebClient();
                mainWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                mainWebBrowser.AllowNavigation = true; 
                mainWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += MainWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
                mainWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(xxx));
                Application.Run();
            });
            wbThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            return wbThread;
        }
```

and this is how I try to do it:

```
        HtmlElement selectType = gDoc.GetElementById("xxx");
        selectType.RaiseEvent("onchange");
```

The code above work well in WinForms project, but in console application nothing happens. Additionally, InvokeScript works well so it is a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `InvokeMember()` method of the `HtmlElement`:

```
 HtmlElement selectType = gDoc.GetElementById("xxx");
 selectType.InvokeMember("change");
```

Comment: It does not fire, problem is it works in WinForms but it does not in console application for some reason, that's my problem. Thanks for reply.

Comment: let me check it, have not done it actually in console app